# What does the variance of cardinal rankings say about the associated ordinal ranking?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Suppose there are a finite number of objects, whose true values are real numbers, with an equal spacing between each value. Suppose that each of n individuals offer an estimate of each of the values of the objects, and the distribution of the estimates of each object are symmetrically distributed around the true value of each object. My question is, does the variance between the n ordinal rankings increase with the variance of the distribution of the estimates around their true value?

Comment: If $n=2$, the true values are fixed, and both estimates are gaussians, then the probability of getting the true ordinal ranking should be some version of the error function. So, yes?